# C++ Armadillo Access Triangular Matrix Elements

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

What would be the most efficient (i.e. balance memory and speed) way to access the upper or lower triangular elements of an Armadillo matrix?  I know I could provide a vector of integers for the elements but as matrices become very large I would like avoid carrying around another large vector.  Or is there an efficient way to quickly create the lower/upper triangular indices?

For example with a 5x5 matrix

```
// C++11 Initialization
arma::mat B = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
                6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
                11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
                16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
                21, 22, 23, 24, 25 };
B.reshape(5,5);


// the matrix
//1    6   11   16   21
//2    7   12   17   22
//3    8   13   18   23
//4    9   14   19   24
//5   10   15   20   25
```

I would like to pull the elements in the lower triangle where the result vector would be:

```
2 3 4 5 8 9 10 14 15 20
```

The only solution I can think of right now is using a `uvec` object.  For example:

```
arma::uvec idx {1,2,3,4,7,8,9,13,14,19);
arma::vec lower_elems = B.elem(idx);
```

The final object doesn't need to be a vector.  I just need to be able to access the elements for various comparisons.  As a simple example let's say I would want to check if they all equal 0.

Answer (score 2):

To check if all the elements in the lower triangle are equal to zero:

```
bool all_zero = all( X.elem(find(trimatl(X))) == 0 );
```

Comment: This is close but it also includes the diagonal.  Is there a way to only look at the triangular elements?  For example, a 3x3 diagonal matrix comes up as false when it should be true for upper or lower triangular if any of the diagonal elements are not zero.

Comment: As far as I know, the definition of triangular matrices always includes the diagonal.  See for example the definitions in [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangularMatrix.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix)

Comment: wiki refers to upper and lower triangular matrices as all the elements **below** and **above** the main diagonal equal to zero.  This does not appear to me to imply that they should include the diagonal.

Comment: Quoting from the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) article: "**lower triangular** if all the entries **above** the main diagonal are **zero**".  In other words, a lower triangular matrix contains the diagonal.  Same definition in [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangularMatrix.html), which explicitly includes the diagonal elements.

Comment: I see, I was misinterpreting the statement.  So to amend my question, how can I check the elements not in the lower triangle?

Comment: Maybe create a temporary with the diagonal set to zero: `mat Y = X; Y.diag().zeros(); bool all_zero = all( Y.elem(find(trimatl(Y))) == 0 );`

Answer (score 0):

Armadillo 9.900 has the functions [trimatu_ind()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#trimat_ind) and [trimatl_ind()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#trimat_ind). These functions provide the indices of the upper and lower triangular portions of a matrix. These indices can be used with [.elem()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat) to access the elements in upper/lower triangular portions.

There are also the functions [.is_trimatu()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#is_trimat) and [.is_trimatl()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#is_trimat) which check if a matrix is upper/lower trinagular.