# filling an upper triangular matrix (including diagonal) with a vector using RcppArmadillo

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I'm learning the features of the `Rcpp` package and have no previous experience with `C++`. I have tried:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::mat VtoMatCpp(int n, 
                    arma::vec x) {

arma::mat V = arma::eye<arma::mat>(n,n) ;

V.elem(find(trimatu(V))) = x;

return(V);

}
```

When I use in R `sourceCpp('fun.cpp')` and then try `VtoMatCpp(2,1:3)` get `Error: Mat::elem(): size mismatch`. It seems that `trimatu` function is not picking the indexes of the diagonal.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use Armadillo within C++ within R when you could accomplish this natively within R?

Comment: @AlexA. I have not tried the alternative but thanks for the tip. By now, I'm just learning `Rcpp` since it seems that provides an "easier" interface for non C++ programmers when calling C++  from within R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting your error because your `find` call is actually finding the non-zero elements (in this case your diagonal elements).  This results in only 2 elements for your `VtoMatCpp(2,1:3)` call where naturally 3 elements is too large to fit in it.

This is somewhat similar to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969869/c-armadillo-access-triangular-matrix-elements) where I actually want to exclude the diagonal elements.  Unfortunately, the best I could come up with right now is to basically copy how R does it with `upper.tri`.  Here is a working example with `RcppArmadillo`.

```
library(inline)

src <- '
using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;

vec x = as<vec>(x_);

int n = as<int>(n_);
mat V = eye<mat>(n,n);

// make empty matrices
mat Z(n,n,fill::zeros);
mat X(n,n,fill::zeros);

// fill matrices with integers
vec idx = linspace<mat>(1,n,n);
X.each_col() += idx;
Z.each_row() += trans(idx);

// assign upper triangular elements
// the >= allows inclusion of diagonal elements
V.elem(find(Z>=X)) = x;

return(wrap(V));
'

fun <- cxxfunction(signature(n_ = "integer", x_ = "vector"), 
                   body=src, plugin="RcppArmadillo")

fun(2,1:3)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    0    3
```

which is exactly the same as `base` R.

```
fun2 <- function(a,b){
dm <- diag(2)
dm[upper.tri(dm, diag=TRUE)] <- 1:3
dm
}

fun2(2,1:3)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    0    3
```

Running a quick benchmark does show that this implementation is faster than `base` R.  Here I wrapped the `base` solution above as `fun2`.

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun(100, seq(5050)), fun2(100, seq(5050)))

Unit: microseconds
                 expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  fun(100, seq(5050)) 117.823 154.106 241.2361 188.2575 242.0360 3392.611   100
 fun2(100, seq(5050)) 545.042 592.988 736.6958 622.7405 650.7475 4057.011   100
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the very same problem this week, could come up with a satisfactory solution thanks to the `arma::trimatl_ind` function. Although the answer from @cdeterman has solved the problem, I believe that my solution is easier to follow and more concise. Moreover, my judgment is that the function implemented in the precious answer was wrong, so I rewrote it too.

```r
library(inline)

fun2 <- function(n, x) {
   dm <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)
   dm[upper.tri(dm, diag=TRUE)] <- x
   dm 
}

src2 <- '
using namespace Rcpp;

vec x = as<vec>(x_);
int n = as<int>(n_);

arma::mat out(n, n, arma::fill::zeros);
arma::uvec lw_idx = arma::trimatl_ind( arma::size(out) );

out.elem(lw_idx) = x;

return out;
'

fun3 <- cxxfunction(signature(n_ = "integer", x_ = "vector"), 
                    body = src, plugin = "RcppArmadillo")

fun3(2, 1:3)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    2
#> [2,]    0    3
```

Finally, I also made a time comparison. My implementation is slightly faster than the previous `Rcpp` solution proposed. However, the most surprising information from the time comparison is how the performance of the function implemented in R has improved.

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
                    "r"     = fun2(100, seq(5050)),
                    "rcpp1" = fun(100, seq(5050)),
                    "rcpp2" = fun3(100, seq(5050))
                )
#> Unit: microseconds
#>   expr    min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#>      r 74.902  84.1845 311.6322  89.2775 149.7765 20276.213   100
#>  rcpp1 67.045 109.1470 141.0202 116.8895 191.0715   229.312   100
#>  rcpp2 54.575 106.3015 136.6472 114.3975 182.0125   231.395   100
```

Below, my session info.

<sup>Created on 2020-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS          
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       America/New_York            
#>  date     2020-12-09                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package        * version     date       lib source        
#>  assertthat       0.2.1       2019-03-21 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  callr            3.5.1       2020-10-13 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  cli              2.2.0       2020-11-20 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  crayon           1.3.4       2017-09-16 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  desc             1.2.0       2018-05-01 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  devtools         2.3.2       2020-09-18 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  digest           0.6.27      2020-10-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  ellipsis         0.3.1       2020-05-15 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  evaluate         0.14        2019-05-28 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fansi            0.4.1       2020-01-08 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fs               1.5.0       2020-07-31 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  glue             1.4.2       2020-08-27 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  highr            0.8         2019-03-20 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  htmltools        0.5.0       2020-06-16 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  inline         * 0.3.16      2020-09-06 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  knitr            1.30        2020-09-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  magrittr         2.0.1       2020-11-17 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  memoise          1.1.0       2017-04-21 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  microbenchmark   1.4-7       2019-09-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgbuild         1.1.0       2020-07-13 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgload          1.1.0       2020-05-29 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  prettyunits      1.1.1       2020-01-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  processx         3.4.5       2020-11-30 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  ps               1.4.0       2020-10-07 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  R6               2.5.0       2020-10-28 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  Rcpp             1.0.5       2020-07-06 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  RcppArmadillo    0.9.900.3.0 2020-09-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  remotes          2.2.0       2020-07-21 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rlang            0.4.9       2020-11-26 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rmarkdown        2.4         2020-09-30 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rprojroot        2.0.2       2020-11-15 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  sessioninfo      1.1.1       2018-11-05 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringi          1.5.3       2020-09-09 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  stringr          1.4.0       2019-02-10 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  testthat         3.0.0       2020-10-31 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  usethis          1.6.3       2020-09-17 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  withr            2.3.0       2020-09-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  xfun             0.18        2020-09-29 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  yaml             2.2.1       2020-02-01 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#> 
#> [1] /home/lcgodoy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0
#> [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#> [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#> [4] /usr/lib/R/library
```