# More efficient way to access lower triangular elements using Armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

Is there a more efficient way to create a vector containing the lower triangular elements of a matrix? For certain algorithms it is useful to just have these elements in a vector.

However, the code below obviously creates copies, when I'd prefer pointers. This is probably not possible given the non-contigous nature of the element positions.

One alternative I thought about is to create an index matrix via `find(trimatu(inmat)!=0)` or so, but I can't imagine that to be more efficient. Finding exact zeroes in a matrix of doubles is usually not very fast, and also there may be actual 0s in within the triangular I am trying to extract.
Something along those lines has been discussed here ([C++ Armadillo Access Triangular Matrix Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969869/c-armadillo-access-triangular-matrix-elements)), however, the question is 5 years old and armadillo has improved a lot since then.

```cpp
vec trimat2vec(mat const& inmat){

  int K = inmat.n_rows;
  int p = K*(K-1)/2;
  vec out(p);

  int counter=0;
  for(int i=0; i<K; i++){
    for(int j=1; j<K; j++){
      if(i<j){
        out(counter)=inmat(j,i);
        counter+=1;
      }
    }
  }
  return(out);
}
```

Comment: I dont understand why you want to use the vector. You will need a index-transformation to get the right element from the vector given some (i,j) index. You could use the same transformation (actually its inverse) to access elements from the vector given their position in the vector without actually copying the elements to a vector

Comment: It's just for convenience. I can use vector operations on the vector. I can store all information from a matrix in a vector which is helpful since armadillo only has cubes but no 4d arrays.

Comment: ok, now I understand ;). I thought I could help without knowing armadillo, but it seems like this really requires a armadillo solution. Fwiw, "sparse matrices" and "flatten matrix to vector" would be what I'd look for.

Comment: Yes, this is armadillo-specific. Armadillo does sparse matrices well too, but it even has functionality to work with upper/lower triangular matrices. It is easy to construct a triangular from a regular square matrix, however, it is not starting from a vector of elements. There is also no built-in function for the code snippet above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, with the new version Armadillo 9.870, there is now a better way to do this. The speed improvement is small, especially on small matrices, but it appears to be consistent. More importantly, the code is much shorter.

I call the new function `trimat2vec_new`.

```cpp
vec trimat2vec_new(mat const& inmat){
  return(inmat.elem(trimatl_ind(size(inmat),-1)));
}
```

Simple benchmark in R:

```r
a=matrix(1:900,30,30)

all(trimat2vec_new(a) == trimat2vec(a))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(trimat2vec_new(a),
               trimat2vec(a),
               times = 1000)
```

yields:

```
Unit: microseconds
              expr   min     lq     mean median    uq    max neval cld
 trimat2vec_new(a) 3.026 3.4060 3.633960  3.557 3.727 20.549  1000  a 
     trimat2vec(a) 3.116 3.6515 3.955116  3.787 3.958 42.981  1000   b
```

I especially like the convenience of the new `trimatl_ind` function. And the small speed improvement.